# Can't npm login to private nexus repo

Tags: node.js, npm

Our private nexus server just had it's certificate renewed and now i'm seeing SSL errors.

I can't even `$ npm login` right now b/c I get this error.

How can I fix/debug this?

```
$ npm login
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://mynexusserver.com/repository/npm-group/-/v1/login failed, reason: write EPROTO 4424951232:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tomcaflisch/.npm/_logs/2019-06-03T17_10_03_093Z-debug.log
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388273/nexus-repo-npm-install-errorconnreset
same issue